# veevalidate reset form typescript does not reset the form

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vee-validate

I have a form with veevalidate. On form submit, the data is emitted to the parent, and then I need to reset the form. Following the veevalidate instructions, it should be possible to reset the form via `$refs`.

- Setup the refs with:
  https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/forms.html#programmatic-access-with-refs
- Reset the form with:
  https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/api/validation-observer.html#methods

My app is in TypeScript, and following the guides, my component looks like this:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <ValidationObserver v-slot="{ handleSubmit }" ref="form">
            <form :model="form" @submit.prevent="handleSubmit(onSubmit)" novalidate>
                <a-input-with-validation
                        :placeholder="placeholder"
                        :label="placeholder"
                        auto-complete="off"
                        name="comment"
                        type="text"
                        v-model="form.comment"
                        rules="required"
                />

                <a-button-submit :translation-key="$t('dict.save')"/>
            </form>
        </ValidationObserver>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
  import { ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider } from 'vee-validate'
  import { OItemCommentFormChildOutput } from '@/components/organisms/forms/OItemCommentFormInterfaces'
  import AInputWithValidation from '@/components/atoms/inputs/AInputWithValidation.vue'
  import AButtonSubmit from '@/components/atoms/buttons/AButtonSubmit.vue'

  @Component({
    components: {
      AButtonSubmit,
      AInputWithValidation,
      ValidationObserver,
      ValidationProvider
    }
  })
  export default class OItemCommentForm extends Vue {
    @Prop()
    comment?: string
    @Prop({ default: true })
    add!: boolean

    $refs!: {
      form: InstanceType<typeof ValidationObserver>;
    }
    placeholder!: string

    form: OItemCommentFormChildOutput = {
      comment: ''
    }

    mounted () {
      this.$refs.form;
    }

    created () {
      this.placeholder = String(this.add ? this.$t('dict.addComment') : this.$t('dict.editComment'))
      this.form.comment = this.comment || ''
    }

    onSubmit () {
      this.$emit('child-output', this.form as OItemCommentFormChildOutput)
      // this.form.comment = ''
      this.$refs.form.reset()
    }
  }
</script>
```

The `a-input-with-validation` component code (from veevalidate):

```html
<template>
    <ValidationProvider
            :vid="vid"
            :name="nameAlt || name"
            :rules="rules"
            v-slot="{ errors, valid }"
    >
        <b-field
                :label="label"
                :prop="name"
                v-bind="$attrs"
                :auto-complete="autoComplete"
                :type="{ 'is-danger': errors[0], 'is-success': valid }"
                :message="errors"
        >
            <b-input
                    :name="name"
                    :type="type"
                    v-bind="$attrs"
                    :placeholder="placeholder"
                    v-model="innerValue"
                    :password-reveal="type === 'password'"
                    novalidate
            />
        </b-field>
    </ValidationProvider>
</template>

<style scoped>
    .AInputWithValidation {}
</style>

<script lang="ts">
  import { Component, Prop, Vue, Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator'
  import { ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider } from 'vee-validate'

  @Component({
    components: {
      ValidationObserver,
      ValidationProvider
    }
  })
  export default class AInputWithValidation extends Vue {
    @Prop({ required: true })
    value!: any
    @Prop({ required: true })
    label!: string
    @Prop({ required: true })
    name!: string
    @Prop({ default: 'off' })
    autoComplete!: string
    @Prop({ default: 'text' })
    type!: string
    @Prop()
    nameAlt?: string
    @Prop()
    placeholder?: string
    @Prop()
    vid?: string
    @Prop()
    rules?: string

    innerValue = ''

    created () {
      if (this.value) {
        this.innerValue = this.value
      }
    }

    @Watch('innerValue')
    innerValueHandle (newVal) {
      this.$emit('child-output', newVal)
      this.$emit('input', newVal)
    }

    @Watch('value')
    valueValueHandle (newVal) {
      this.innerValue = newVal
    }

  }
</script>
```

The app compiles just fine, so seemingly no TS errors. On submit, the data is emitted correctly. But when I try to call the `reset` method, nothing happens. The form is not reset, and the input value stays the same. If I also force the comment within the form to an empty string, this triggers the validator to display errors.

How can I reset the form after form submit and clear the contents of the form without triggering the validation errors?

(moving the `ref="form"` onto the form tag does not do anything either :/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ValidationObserver`'s `reset()` only resets the validation state, not the form fields. While the docs include a [form-reset demo that manually clears the fields](https://codesandbox.io/s/x6wze?file=/src/Demo.vue:1080-1138), you could alternatively invoke [`HTMLFormElement.reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) on the `<form>` element to reset the fields to their initial values. The `<form>` element can be accessed from the `SubmitEvent`'s [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target):

```js
export default class OItemCommentForm extends Vue {

  async onSubmit(e) {
    // Wait microtick for models to update before resetting validation state
    await this.$nextTick()
    this.$refs.form.reset()

    // Reset form in next macrotick
    setTimeout(() => e.target.reset())
  }
}
```

The key is to reset the form in the next [macrotick](https://javascript.info/event-loop#macrotasks-and-microtasks) (via `setTimeout` with a zero timeout).

[image: Edit Reset form after submit]

Comment: This does not work however with veevalidate though as the event is not passed to the submit handler :/

Comment: [`ValidationObserver.handleSubmit`](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/blob/59f5c0fbd7e9f980821b56d29c0694f2957c11be/src/components/Observer.ts#L182) simply returned early if `validate()` failed. Otherwise, it would call the given callback. Your own `submit`-handler could do that itself with `this.$refs.form.validate()`, which is what I've shown in the linked demo.

Comment: If you prefer to use `handleSubmit`, it looks like you'll have to clear the form fields yourself (as prescribed by the VeeValidate docs). I'm not sure of any other workaround.